# Are there sets in the unit cube that cannot be in the domain of any finitely-additive, isometry-invariant probability measure?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, banach-tarski

The Vitali construction implies (given choice) the existence of a set such that for any translation-invariant, countably additive probability measure on $[0,1]$, that set is nonmeasurable and has inner measure 0.

By contrast, Banach showed that there exists a translation-invariant, *finitely* additive probability measure defined on all subsets of the unit interval.  However the Banach-Tarski paradox shows that there is no finitely additive, isometry-invariant probability measure defined on all subsets of $[0,1]^3$.  Moreover, it tells us that there is a set $\{X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5\}$ of subsets of $[0,1]^3$ such that any finitely additive, isometry-invariant probability measure on $[0,1]^3$ must treat at least one of $X_i$ as nonmeasurable.  However it is not immediately obvious that it implies that any single *one* of those $X_i$ is forced be nonmeasurable, or that any of them is forced to have inner measure 0.

So, my question is:

- Is there $X\subseteq [0,1]^3$ such that for any finitely additive, isometry-invariant probability measure $P$ on $[0,1]^3$, $X$ is not $P$-measurable and has inner $P$-measure 0?

And if the answer to that one is ‘no’:

- Is there $X\subseteq [0,1]^3$ such that for any finitely additive, isometry-invariant probability measure $P$ on $[0,1]^3$, $X$ is not $P$-measurable?
- Are there finite sets $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ of subsets of $[0,1]^3$ such that for any finitely additive, isometry-invariant probability measure $P$ on $[0,1]^3$, at least one $X_i$ is not $P$-measurable and has inner $P$-measure 0?

Comment: What is the definition of "non-trivial" for a finitely-additive measure?

Comment: I meant 'assigns values other than 0'.  (My real interest is in probability measures.)

Comment: So, you allow finitely additive measures valued in $\{0,\infty\}$?

Comment: Oops... I see that the way I asked the question those are allowed, but then the thing I said about what the Banach-Tarski paradox shows is false since you can have an isometry-invariant, finitely-additive measure that assigns $\infty$ to every nonempty set.  What I really care about is probability measures on $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^3$.  I'll edit the question to say this. (Unless you know some more elegant way of getting essentially the same effect?).

Comment: @Cian The space $[0,1]^3$ doesn't have too many isometries. So by "isometry-invariant" you probably mean invariance with respect to the isometries of the whole space $\mathbb{R}^3$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  The condition is that when $f$ is an isometry on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $X\subseteq [0,1]^3$ and $fX\subseteq [0,1]^3$, $P(fX) = P(X)$.